# How to get a value using Bigdecimal mathematical operations in Java

Tags: java, selenium, bigdecimal

I am trying to get the Tax value of a product (Tax % I am passing as static value)

using the Bigdecimal but getting the error below is my code

```
        double  dis,amount,s;
        BigDecimal taxprice;




        List<WebElement> firstproductSubtotalprice = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='m-order-detail-item-name']/span"));
        BigDecimal firstproductSubtotalpricevalue = null;
        for (WebElement webElement : firstproductSubtotalprice) {
            String priceText = webElement.getText();
            if (priceText != null && priceText.length() > 0) {
                firstproductSubtotalpricevalue = new BigDecimal(priceText.replace('$', ' ').trim());
                System.out.println("The First Product Subtotal Price is: "+ firstproductSubtotalpricevalue);
                break;
            }
        }



        List<WebElement> firstproductTaxprice = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Tax')]/following-sibling::span[1]"));
        BigDecimal firstproductTaxpriceValue = null;
        for (WebElement webElement : firstproductTaxprice) {
            String priceText = webElement.getText();
            if (priceText != null && priceText.length() > 0) {
                firstproductTaxpriceValue = new BigDecimal(priceText.replace('$', ' ').trim());
                System.out.println("The First Product Tax Price is: "+ firstproductTaxpriceValue);
                break;
            }
        }

        taxprice = firstproductSubtotalpricevalue;

        dis=10;

        s=100-dis;

        BigDecimal  c= firstproductTaxpriceValue;


               BigDecimal   a = taxprice.multiply(new BigDecimal(s)); 

               BigDecimal  b =  a.divide(a, 100);



               System.out.println(a+"/"+b+" = "+c);
```

Using the above code I want to get the tax value and want to compare with the firstproductTaxpriceValue,
 if the tax amount is equal to firstproductTaxpriceValue then my test cases is pass if not fail.

Please help me to get the tax value

Comment: What error? And where in the code?

Comment: Please share the error stack trace to further help you with the issue.

Comment: I am getting this error,                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid rounding mode
 at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1558)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1622)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding mode is not provided while dividing.

Below is the declaration of the method:

```
public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)
```

Try this:

```
 BigDecimal  b =  a.divide(new BigDecimal(100),2,RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

Where **1st argument**, `new BigDecimal(100)` is the value you want to divide to

**2nd argument**,`2` is the scale or no. of decimal places

**3rd argument**, `RoundingMode.CEILING` is the mode with which way you want to round the outcome.

Comment: If i remove C i am getting the belwo output which is not correct                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
   The First Product Subtotal Price is: 94.95
The First Product Tax Price is: 11.50
The Tax Amount is 8545.50/85.46 =

Comment: double  dis,amount,markedprice,s;
               
 markedprice=1000;
 
        dis=25;  // 25 mean 25%   
 
 System.out.println("markedprice= "+markedprice);
 
 System.out.println("discount rate="+dis);
         
        s=100-dis;
 
 amount= (s*markedprice)/100;
 
 System.out.println("amount after discount="+amount);                                               my scenario is similor to this here marketprice is firstproductSubtotalpricevalue

Comment: I am not able to understand the code in comments, can you please update the question or post a new one for new issue

Comment: https://javatutoring.com/java-program-to-calculate-discount/ refer this my scenario is similar to this and my case I want to get the Tax amount

Comment: @user3538483 I am sure you are missing something, I executed the same for taxprice = 11.50, s = 90 and I got A as 1035.0 and B as 10.35

Answer (score 0):

You do `BigDecimal b = a.divide(a, 100)` at the end of your code. `100` is not a valid input here.

Use one of these:

```
0 (ROUND_UP)
1 (ROUND_DOWN)
2 (ROUND_CEILING)
3 (ROUND_FLOOR)
4 (ROUND_HALF_UP)
5 (ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
6 (ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
7 (ROUND_UNNECESSARY)
```